# サーバーサイドとフロントのデータのやり取り

Tags: javascript

サーバーサイドではPHPやRubyなどの言語を使いますが、
ブラウザ側ではJavaScript一択ですよね。

そのJavaScriptとのデータのやり取りはどのようにしていけばよいのでしょうか。
ページにJSONを埋め込んでパースしたり、ajaxでデータを取得するための通信を行ったりするくらいでしょうか。

未だ経験したことないので、様々なシチュエーションに基づいて、
どのようなやり方、工夫がよいのかお聞かせください。

Answer (score 5):

質問に挙がっているようなやり方以外にも

- [Websocket](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)
- [WebRTC](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC)

を使った方法などもあります。

ざっくりと言うと
WebSocketは双方向の通信を効率良くできる通信方法で、
WebRTCはP2P(クライアント同士での直接通信)が売りで、対戦ゲームやビデオチャットなどをするのに向いています。

ajaxも最近はXMLHttpRequestだけではなくfetchという新しいAPIが出てきていたりもしているようです。

参考: [Fetch API 解説、または Web において "Fetch する" とは何か？ - Block Rockin’ Codes](http://jxck.hatenablog.com/entry/whatwg-fetch)

Answer (score 0):

他にも [SSE (Server Sent Events)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#server-sent-events)というのもあります。publisher / subscriber 型で,プッシュ配信することができます。リンク先に`EventSource`APIのスペックがあります。

ペイロードにJSONを使った、実例は[こちら](https://bitcoinity.org/markets/btcchina/CNY)。ビットコインの現在値を[ストリーム](https://bitcoinity.org/ev/markets/markets_btcchina_CNY)で配信しています。